# Inner Join Delete in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to join 2 tables together and do a delete on it.

```
DELETE TableA 
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN
TableB b on b.Id = a.Id
where title like 'test'
```

The above is what I come up with however I keep getting

> *The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint*

I thought if I merge the 2 tables together then I will delete both at the same time and no constraints would be conflicted.

Am I missing something in my query?

Comment: Only one table is subject to delete (TableA here). This syntax is just for filtering the rows to delete.

Comment: Do you have your constraints to `CASCADE DELETE`?  If you can add that, then it would help with these messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First try to delete `TableB` with that title condition
Then delete those records in `TableA`

```
DELETE FROM TableB
WHERE Id IN 
( SELECT Id FROM TableA WHERE title = 'test')

DELETE FROM TableA
WHERE title = 'test'
```

Referential Constraints blocks you from deleting rows in `TableA` when you still have reference in `TableB`

Comment: Sorry. I probably should have done a.Title = 'test'. TableB has no title column. TableB is a mapping table so it just contains data to map a few tables together.

Comment: in my query i am looking for title column in TableA only.

Comment: Ah I see. Still getting the foreign key constraint that is between those 2 tables. I see TableB has another foreign key but it is not complaining about that one.

Answer (score 12):

try this:

```
DELETE TableA 
FROM TableA 
INNER JOIN
TableB b on b.Id = TableA.Id
where TableA.title like 'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would delete one after the other with cascade constraint.

Comment: I was thinking of a cascade but I think I have to alter the table then and I don't want to touch the table design. If it is possible to set it on the fly then I would do it.